# How to pass indexPath row data in collectionView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

How do I use 
`let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow? .Row` 
code in table view in collectionView? I want to pass the indexPath row data of the selected cell.

I have implemented the table view so far.

tableView source code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? MovieDetailViewController,

            let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            else {
                return
        }
        destination.movieId = movieList?.movies[index].id

    }
```

The code I need is a collection view version of 
`let index = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow? .Row`

Comment: try using `indexPathsForSelectedItems`

Comment: @koropok ```destination.movieId = movieList? .movies [index] .id``` This code is not implemented.

Comment: i'm sorry but i think you'll have to provide more information before we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the indexPaths of selectedItems in a UICollectionView, use

> **indexPathsForSelectedItems**
>
> The value of this property is an array of NSIndexPath objects, each of
>   which corresponds to a single selected item. If there are no selected
>   items, the value of this property is nil.

If the `allowsMultipleSelection` is `true`, `indexPathsForSelectedItems` can contain *multiple elements*, otherwise only a *single element*.

So, `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` in a `tableView` will correspond to

```
collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
```